# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset. I test the ip of domain name，the other computer visit same domain name

Tags: java, linux, curl

This happens on my linux server
when I curl this domain name it gets 【Connection reset by peer】

[image]

And If I curl the ip of this domain name，everything is ok

[image]

Also I curl this domain name on my windows laptop，it's also okay

[image]

And sometimes it works okay on my linux server
Anyone has idea what's the problem here？Or is there any way I can test to get more information of difference in this？

Comment: Try with `-H 'Host: oa.jdgzf.net` vs. `-H 'Host: 183.195.115.146`

Comment: @darw  curl http://oa.jdgzf.net:80/seeyon/rest/token/wechat/【】 -H "host:oa.jdgzf.net"    ← not success                                curl -v http://183.195.115.146:80/seeyon/rest/token/wechat/【】 -H "host:oa.jdgzf.net"   ← not success                                curl http://oa.jdgzf.net:80/seeyon/rest/token/wechat/【】 -H "host:183.195.115.146"           ← success                  【so i guess there is something wrong with my linux server's dns？

Comment: no, it's that the server running on `oa.jdgzf.net:80` checks for `Host` header and applies different routing rules based on its value

Comment: but i test  curl oa.jdgzf.net:80/seeyon/rest/token/wechat【】 -H "host:oa.jdgzf.net"  on my laptop it is success to visit